# Making an Array in an Array into Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Best way to convert

```
a = [['tokyo', '10', '20'],['newyork', '30', '40'],['singapore', '50', '60']];
```

to

```
a = [{city:'tokyo', lat:'10', lon:'20'},{city:'newyork', lat:'30', lon:'40'},{city:'singapore', lat:'50', lon:'60'}];
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried yourself? I'd use `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: Sorry but the example you have given is not correctly formatted so it's confusing what you really want to get. there's a "{" that is not closed anywhere. Not clear, do you want all those items to be in one object or an array of objects ? Either way you can use reduce on arrays to do quite a lot'

Comment: Edited it should be clearer now. I meant to have multiple objects in a single array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`#map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to convert it into the array of *objects* - see demo below:

```js
var a = [['tokyo', '10', '20'],['newyork', '30', '40'],['singapore', '50', '60']];

var result = a.map(function(e) {
  return {
    city: e[0],
    lat: e[1],
    lon: e[2]
  }
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! Taking a javascript class been stuck on this for a while. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about best way, but I think it's readable. It uses a method called `.map()` that goes through each element in an array, and typically modifies it to your liking. See the below code for an example.

```
a = [['tokyo', '10', '20'],['newyork', '30', '40'],['singapore', '50', 
'60']];

const newArrayOfObjects = a.map(val => {
  return { city: val[0], lat: val[1], lon: val[2] }
})

newArrayOfObjects
```

MDN reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map